# How can I set a Removable External Device as a built-in Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, symbolic-link, sd-card, removable-media

I am using SSD with my laptop and running out of free space..

So I bought an 64GB microSD card as a secondary storage.

But, when I launch My Computer, the SD card drive is recognized as, of course, an external removable device.

And now, I want to change the SD card drive like a 'real hard drive' even if it's just a fake.

So, if there is any solution, please let me know..
Thanks a lot!

---

I tried mlink to make alias to my SD card. The alias was created perfectly but it couldn't fake the cloud storage service to recognize the mlink as a hard drive.  nice programmers.. no fake allowed.. 
Does anyone know other options? Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg because of a cloud storage service. my cloud service only allows sync of local hard drives, not portable devices. any solution? thankx

Comment: @klados symlink the card to some directory on your drive. Use command-line tool called `mklink`.

Comment: @gronostaj solved! great! not exactly what I wanted(making a hard-disk symlink), but it works. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @gronostaj I'm here again. mlink worked perfectly but it couldn't fake my cloud service. it includes not only Dropbox but a few more minor services. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to:

**Option 1**

- Run > diskmgmt.msc
- Select the disk you are trying to copy > right click > Change Drive
  Letter and Paths
- Click on Add > Mount in the following empty NTFS folder

and follow the rest of the instructions?

**Option 2**

Another option - overkill as hell - is to use TrueCrypt to encrypt the removable disk and mount it as fixed (done by default).

Cheers

Comment: YES!! It really works. At a glance, this method looks similar to the earlier one but totally different inside. Thanks @Andre de Miranda

Comment: (still one of my cloud storages doesn't work that way but the others do)

Comment: @klados I imagine you used the mount point option. Have you also tried using the TrueCrypt option? It is overkill but should work with all apps.

Comment: yes that option works! but when I reboot, the cloud storage service starts before the TrueCrpyt mounting procedure. So, I gave up to use one of the services. Thank you.